# Get Differences in arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, compare

I am using two divs in HTML in which I have multiple spans. Im providing a delete button to the user with which he can delete some spans (which he has to select before). And now want to determine which span-elements have been deleted.

How can I compare two arrays which are holding Selector-Results?

Is there a possibility to use something like the IEqualityComparer in C#?

Comment: Do add your code as well to understand the context. Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow a jquery solution

```js
var firstArray = $("span.odd");
var secondArray = $("span.even");

var compareResult = $(firstArray).not(secondArray).length === 0 && $(secondArray).not(firstArray).length === 0;

console.log("Collections are equal:",compareResult);

var collectionDiff = secondArray.filter(function(){
  return secondArray.filter(this).length
});

console.log("diff",collectionDiff.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <span class="odd">span 1</span>
    <span class="even">span 2</span>
    <span class="odd">span 3</span>
    <span class="even">span 4</span>
    <span class="odd">span 5</span>
    <span class="even">span 6</span>
    <span class="odd">span 7</span>
    <span class="even">span 8</span>
    <span class="odd">span 9</span>
    <span class="even">span 10</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom function like this.

```
 var array1= [4,8,9,10,34],
    array2= [4,9,10,11,12,13],
    differnce = arrayDiffr(array1,array2);


        function arrayDiffr(a1, a2)
        {
          var a = [], diff = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
                a[a1[i]] = true;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
                if (a[a2[i]]) {
                    delete a[a2[i]];
                } else {
                    a[a2[i]] = true;
                }
            }

            for (var k in a) {
                diff.push(k);
            }

            return diff;
        }
        console.log(differnce) //differnce return :[8,11,12,13,34]
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do something as follows. I use the dataset API to mark the spans to be deleted. In addition to that there are some ES6 functionalities utilized such as the spread operator. So make sure your browser is fine with it. The code is pretty self explanatory.

```js
function getDifference(a,b){
  return a.filter(e => !b.some(f => f.textContent === e.textContent));
}

function toggleDelete(e){
  var del = e.currentTarget.dataset.toBeDeleted === "true";
  e.currentTarget.dataset.toBeDeleted = del ? "false" : "true";
  del = !del;
  e.currentTarget.className = del ? "tbd" : "";
}

function deleteSelectedSpans(e){
  var deletedSpans;
  for (var span of spans) span.dataset.toBeDeleted === "true" && span.parentElement.removeChild(span);
  spans = [...myDiv.querySelectorAll("span")];
  deletedSpans = getDifference(spansCopy,spans);
  for (var deletedSpan of deletedSpans) deletedSpansList.appendChild(deletedSpan);
}

var spans = [...myDiv.querySelectorAll("span")],
spansCopy = spans.slice();
for (var span of spans) {
  span.dataset.toBeDeleted = "false";
  span.addEventListener("click",toggleDelete);
}

myButton.addEventListener("click",deleteSelectedSpans);
```

```css
div    {text-align       : center;
        background-color : white;
        border           : solid thistle 2px;
        border-radius    : 5px;
        padding          : 10px;}
span   {background-color : white;
        border           : solid thistle 2px;
        border-radius    : 5px;
        align            : center}
.tbd   {background-color : tomato;
        color            : white;
        border           : solid pink 2px;
        border-radius    : 5px}
button {display          : block;
        margin           : 10px auto}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <span>Span-1</span>
  <span>Span-2</span>
  <span>Span-3</span>
  <span>Span-4</span>
  <span>Span-5</span>
  <span>Span-6</span>
  <button id="myButton">Delete Selected Spans</button>
  <div id="deletedSpansList">Deleted Spans:</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share my result:

I had one jquery filter call to get which things are selected and can now use this collection of things to call another filter to specify the results further and further to some specific attributes.

@Vlad Ionut had the best suggestion, thanks for this.